# pandas vs mysql creating a report generator for windows

Tags: python, mysql, excel, pandas, automation

i have a "database in the form of an excel file" used to generate reports, i want to build an app to generate the report using data exchange with this database, on windows, i'm trying to learn pandas through this,
1- am i wasting my time and should be using another approach instead
2- i need to create a data frame automatically, so i'm trying to extract column names for the data frame from my excel table

3- i managed to store the first row " the column names" in a list, how can i create a dataframe with heders using this list.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import xlrd 

cwd = os.getcwd()
book = xlrd.open_workbook('LISTERC.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")

count = 0
hdr = []
for c in range(10):
    if (sheet.cell(0,c).value != ''):
    count +=1
    hdr.append (sheet.cell(0,c).value)


DF = pd.DataFrame(*zip(hdr))
```

Comment: You can use https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: I think it's best if you split your question up into multiple questions. It's hard for people to answer too many questions in one go.